# replacing menu in a master page - Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of replacing a menu using Jquery and a sharepoint list.
But the problem i have is where to place my js menu script the master page.
I tried disabling the asp: menu and the content place holders by setting visible to false and the place my div with the new menu just before the first content place holder.
But i discover that any time i try and hover the menu.The hover kind of get blocked and it doesn't show.
What do i need to take off and where should my js menu be place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery isn't a bad way to override the menu on selected pages, but I wouldn't use it to render the navigation globally.  Instead I would look to replace or supplement the existing navigation provider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Do you have any resources you can forward me to regarding what you suggested for sharepoint 2010?
I'll try out the xmlProvider

Answer (score 0):

I am planning on building the same functionality that is changing the top nav menu using Jquery and Web Service. I have built the css and jquery and put it in to the master page but as of now hard coding the ul and li values. I want to make it dynamically generated from a SP List. Can you throw some light on it or share some of your js code.

Thanks,
MAC